# About AdViews, how many can i implement?

Tags: android, admob, ads

I've got following problem.

I got two different Activities in my Android application. Now I wanted to add an AdView on each of these activities.

It worked for me adding one adView to "BANNER" and the other one to "SMART_BANNER".

But now, when I try to set both AdViews (the one activity and the other activity), to "SMART_BANNER", I noticed that one of these Banners won't show up.

This made me ask several questions:

How many adViews am i allowed to implement in one app?

How many adVies am i allowed to implement in one single activity?

Why doesn't it work when using two SMART_BANNER in one app? Why does it work when using one BANNER and one SMART_BANNER adView in one class?

I hope you can help me.

Comment: I'm using two smart banners in the same fragment without any problems. Please post some code, otherwise it will be very difficult to help you.

Answer (score 1):

It is against Admob TOS for you to display 2 AdViews on the one Activity.

But it is totally acceptable to display more than one AdView within your app. But in reality you only want to display AdViews where the user spends most of their time.